# Buildozer getting error about threading, site-packages, sh.ErrorReturnCode_1 and sutff

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

Before that I was able to get apk quite well, extra I assigned the clock.thread module in my main.py file as @mainthread to a few functions in the kivy module and I don't know if it's relevant, but before that I rooted my own phone. Additionally I run buildozer from my phone

this is the all active buildozer content except title,version .etc

buildozer:

```
`[app]
source.include_exts=py,png,jpg,kv,ttf 
requirements=python3,kivy=2.0.0,sqlite3,requests,jnius,pillow,android 
osx.kivy_version=2.0.0 
android.api=30 
android.logcat.filters=*:Spython:D 
android.archs=arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a 
android_allow_bakcup=True
p4a.bootstrap=sdl2
ios.kivy_ios_url=https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.ios_kivy_branch=master 
ios.ios_deploy_url=https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch=1.0.0
ios.codesign.allowed=false
[buildozer]
log_level=2
warn_on_root=0
```

error:

```
[DEBUG]:   -> running configure --host=aarch64-linux-android --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --enable-shared --enable-ipv6 ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=yes ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no --without-ensurepip ac_cv_little_endian_double=yes ac_cv_header_sys_eventfd_h=no --prefix=/usr/local --exec-prefix=/usr/local --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --with-openssl=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/openssl/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/openssl1.1
[DEBUG]:    checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
[DEBUG]:    checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android
[DEBUG]:    checking for python3.9... no
[DEBUG]:    checking for python3... python3
[DEBUG]:    checking for python interpreter for cross build... configure: error: python3.9 interpreter not found
Exception in thread background thread for pid 64067:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/configure --host=aarch64-linux-android --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --enable-shared --enable-ipv6 ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=yes ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no --without-ensurepip ac_cv_little_endian_double=yes ac_cv_header_sys_eventfd_h=no --prefix=/usr/local --exec-prefix=/usr/local --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --with-openssl=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/openssl/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/openssl1.1

  STDOUT:
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android
checking for python3.9... no
checking for python3... python3
checking for python interpreter for cross build... configure: error: python3.9 interpreter not found


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1312, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 734, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 212, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 504, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/python3/__init__.py", line 321, in build_arch
    shprint(
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/configure --host=aarch64-linux-android --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --enable-shared --enable-ipv6 ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=yes ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no --without-ensurepip ac_cv_little_endian_double=yes ac_cv_header_sys_eventfd_h=no --prefix=/usr/local --exec-prefix=/usr/local --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --with-openssl=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/openssl/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/openssl1.1

  STDOUT:
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android
checking for python3.9... no
checking for python3... python3
checking for python interpreter for cross build... configure: error: python3.9 interpreter not found


  STDERR:

# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=OpImmortal', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy==2.0.0,sqlite3,requests,jnius,pillow,android,threading', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_VERSION = '11.11.3.6-1'
#     NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all'
#     COLAB_JUPYTER_TRANSPORT = 'ipc'
#     NV_NVML_DEV_VERSION = '11.8.86-1'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcudnn8'
#     CGROUP_MEMORY_EVENTS = '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory.events /var/colab/cgroup/jupyter-children/memory.events'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libnccl-dev=2.16.2-1+cuda11.8'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_VERSION = '2.16.2-1'
#     VM_GCE_METADATA_HOST = '169.254.169.253'
#     HOSTNAME = '8b6236c6aad0'
#     TBE_RUNTIME_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8011'
#     GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '3'
#     NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA = ('cuda>=11.8 brand=tesla,driver>=450,driver<451 '
 'brand=tesla,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=unknown,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=nvidia,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=nvidiartx,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=geforce,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=geforcertx,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=quadro,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=quadrortx,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=titan,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=titanrtx,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=tesla,driver>=510,driver<511 brand=unknown,driver>=510,driver<511 '
 'brand=nvidia,driver>=510,driver<511 brand=nvidiartx,driver>=510,driver<511 '
 'brand=geforce,driver>=510,driver<511 brand=geforcertx,driver>=510,driver<511 '
 'brand=quadro,driver>=510,driver<511 brand=quadrortx,driver>=510,driver<511 '
 'brand=titan,driver>=510,driver<511 brand=titanrtx,driver>=510,driver<511 '
 'brand=tesla,driver>=515,driver<516 brand=unknown,driver>=515,driver<516 '
 'brand=nvidia,driver>=515,driver<516 brand=nvidiartx,driver>=515,driver<516 '
 'brand=geforce,driver>=515,driver<516 brand=geforcertx,driver>=515,driver<516 '
 'brand=quadro,driver>=515,driver<516 brand=quadrortx,driver>=515,driver<516 '
 'brand=titan,driver>=515,driver<516 brand=titanrtx,driver>=515,driver<516')
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libcublas-dev-11-8=11.11.3.6-1'
#     NV_NVTX_VERSION = '11.8.86-1'
#     COLAB_JUPYTER_IP = '172.28.0.12'
#     NV_CUDA_CUDART_DEV_VERSION = '11.8.89-1'
#     NV_LIBCUSPARSE_VERSION = '11.7.5.86-1'
#     COLAB_LANGUAGE_SERVER_PROXY_ROOT_URL = 'http://172.28.0.1:8013/'
#     NV_LIBNPP_VERSION = '11.8.0.86-1'
#     NCCL_VERSION = '2.16.2-1'
#     KMP_LISTEN_PORT = '6000'
#     TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true'
#     ENV = '/root/.bashrc'
#     PWD = '/content'
#     TBE_EPHEM_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8009'
#     COLAB_LANGUAGE_SERVER_PROXY_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = '30s'
#     TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE = 'libcudnn8=8.9.0.131-1+cuda11.8'
#     NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility'
#     COLAB_JUPYTER_TOKEN = ''
#     LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20230608'
#     NV_NVPROF_DEV_PACKAGE = 'cuda-nvprof-11-8=11.8.87-1'
#     NV_LIBNPP_PACKAGE = 'libnpp-11-8=11.8.0.86-1'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libnccl-dev'
#     TCLLIBPATH = '/usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.20'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_VERSION = '11.11.3.6-1'
#     COLAB_KERNEL_MANAGER_PROXY_HOST = '172.28.0.12'
#     NVIDIA_PRODUCT_NAME = 'CUDA'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcublas-dev-11-8'
#     USE_AUTH_EPHEM = '1'
#     NV_CUDA_CUDART_VERSION = '11.8.89-1'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     CUDA_VERSION = '11.8.0'
#     CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE = 'libcublas-11-8=11.11.3.6-1'
#     NV_CUDA_NSIGHT_COMPUTE_DEV_PACKAGE = 'cuda-nsight-compute-11-8=11.8.0-1'
#     COLAB_RELEASE_TAG = 'release-colab-20230622-060123-RC01'
#     PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL = 'NO'
#     KMP_TARGET_PORT = '9000'
#     CLICOLOR = '1'
#     KMP_EXTRA_ARGS = ('--logtostderr --listen_host=172.28.0.12 --target_host=172.28.0.12 '
 '--tunnel_background_save_url=https://colab.research.google.com/tun/m/cc48301118ce562b961b3c22d803539adc1e0c19/m-s-xi4hmhnt9cbm '
 '--tunnel_background_save_delay=10s '
 '--tunnel_periodic_background_save_frequency=30m0s '
 '--enable_output_coalescing=true --output_coalescing_required=true')
#     NV_LIBNPP_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libnpp-dev-11-8=11.8.0.86-1'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcublas-11-8'
#     COLAB_KERNEL_MANAGER_PROXY_PORT = '6000'
#     CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3'
#     NV_LIBNPP_DEV_VERSION = '11.8.0.86-1'
#     ENABLE_DIRECTORYPREFETCHER = '1'
#     NO_GCE_CHECK = 'False'
#     JPY_PARENT_PID = '79'
#     PYTHONPATH = '/env/python'
#     TERM = 'xterm-color'
#     NV_LIBCUSPARSE_DEV_VERSION = '11.7.5.86-1'
#     GIT_PAGER = 'cat'
#     LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
#     NV_CUDNN_VERSION = '8.9.0.131'
#     SHLVL = '0'
#     PAGER = 'cat'
#     COLAB_LANGUAGE_SERVER_PROXY = '/usr/colab/bin/language_service'
#     NV_CUDA_LIB_VERSION = '11.8.0-1'
#     NVARCH = 'x86_64'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_DEV = 'libcudnn8-dev=8.9.0.131-1+cuda11.8'
#     NV_CUDA_COMPAT_PACKAGE = 'cuda-compat-11-8'
#     MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE = 'libnccl2=2.16.2-1+cuda11.8'
#     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
#     COLAB_GPU = ''
#     GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16'
#     NV_CUDA_NSIGHT_COMPUTE_VERSION = '11.8.0-1'
#     NV_NVPROF_VERSION = '11.8.87-1'
#     COLAB_FILE_HANDLER_ADDR = 'localhost:3453'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libnccl2'
#     COLAB_DEBUG_ADAPTER_MUX_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_VERSION = '2.16.2-1'
#     PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
#     DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive'
#     COLAB_BACKEND_VERSION = 'next'
#     OLDPWD = '/'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '30'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2`
```

Edit: samething happen when this simple code (image file size 80mb)

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class AnimationApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return 
 Image(source="/data/data/com.pkgteam.opimmortal/files/app/big.png")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AnimationApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

(I want to curse) It worked after I removed the code that runs the whole ios packaging process (from buildozer.spec)